# How to plot an oscillator above last price in PineScript on TradingView?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm trying to plot an oscillator in the same pane as price
I would have it just above (or at the same height) of last price
plot(bbr / 1000 + bbr_plot_pos, "%B Scaled")

How could achieve this?

Oscillator just above price level:
[image]

I tried using a var float with close or close[0] but it plots the series at the height of the first bar in history (as I understand it starts from there, and store first bar price)
var float bbr_plot_pos = close[0]

I tried with
if barstate.islast bbr_plot_pos = close
similar result

Is that even possible or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `scale=scale.none`. The following plots the RSI on yhe main cahrt with no scaling.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", overlay=true, format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true, scale=scale.none)

ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "Bollinger Bands" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

rsiLengthInput = input.int(14, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput = input.source(close, "Source", group="RSI Settings")
maTypeInput = input.string("SMA", title="MA Type", options=["SMA", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput = input.int(14, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")
bbMultInput = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="BB StdDev", group="MA Settings")

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsiMA = ma(rsi, maLengthInput, maTypeInput)
isBB = maTypeInput == "Bollinger Bands"

plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
plot(rsiMA, "RSI-based MA", color=color.yellow)
rsiUpperBand = hline(70, "RSI Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "RSI Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
rsiLowerBand = hline(30, "RSI Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(rsiUpperBand, rsiLowerBand, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="RSI Background Fill")
bbUpperBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA + ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Upper Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
bbLowerBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA - ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Lower Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
fill(bbUpperBand, bbLowerBand, color= isBB ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na, title="Bollinger Bands Background Fill")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Vitruvius, I tried and it's working quite ok. I would offset it a bit (above or below) but that's not so easy. Also I have moving averages that got flattened this way :/

Comment: Well, that's pretty much all you can do in one window.

Comment: I'll make it work with it :) thank you!